# How to implement table relation into entity object?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-relationship

I have two tables in a database:

```
Grade
+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| int id | varchar name | varchar teacher |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+
|      1 | CL-2A        | E. Wright       |
|      2 | CL-2B        | B. Springsteen  |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+

Student
+--------+------------------+-----------+
| int id | varchar name     | int grade |
+--------+------------------+-----------+
|      1 | Michael Wallings |         1 |
|      2 | Rowen Tress      |         1 |
|      3 | Alys Harverd     |         2 |
|      4 | Jeff Bass        |         1 |
|      5 | Harry Farewell   |         2 |
+--------+------------------+-----------+
```

As you've probably seen already, **Student.grade** refers to **Grade.id** with a foreign key.

Now I've made some entity objects for both tables. But how do I implement to relation between **Student** and **Grade**?

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int grade;   // Keep the grade as an int.
    ...
```

or

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Grade grade; // Hold a reference to the corresponding entity object Grade.
    ...
```

or something?

The second code snippet requires me to also get the grade entity object derived from the database.

Comment: what technology you are using for persisting in db;

Comment: @RadhaMohan: What do you mean 'technology'? (Can you provide an example?)

Comment: means hibernate or mybatis, or plain JDBC

Comment: @tereško - Again, you're globally re-tagging things that have nothing to do with asp.net mvc.  Just because someone uses the mvc tag doesn't automatically mean they meant asp.net-mvc.

Comment: Well .. it definitely has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: @tereško - and what part of this users profile suggests they're an asp.net-mvc user?  Considering their posting history is about android, php, and the like.. this just reinforces my point that you are too quick to leap to the conclusion that any mention of mvc means asp.net-mvc.

Comment: @RadhaMohan: I'm using plain JDBC.